# How to resume counter from last ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have added some input fields in a form using counter method, and I saved that form. When I am trying to add fields again in to the form, the counter is starting from 0.

For example, I added 5 input fields. Those input field model values have taken 0,1,2,3,4,5. When I started adding fields after saving form, the counter is taking again from starting,  means the result has come like this: {0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,-----}.

How can I start the counter from last ended number?

**Updated**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile) {
$scope.singleFields = [];
    var counter = 0;
    $scope.addNew_SingleField = function (index) {
        $scope.singleFields[counter] = {single: 'untitled'};
        var singlehtml = '<div ng-click="selectSingle(singleFields[\'' + counter + '\'])">\n\
<label>{{singleFields[' + counter + '].single}}</label>\n\
<input type="text"></div>';
        var single = $compile(singlehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(single);
        ++counter;
    };
    $scope.selectSingle = function (val) {
        $scope.singleField = val;
        $scope.showName = true;
    };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0-beta.2/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
 <button ng-click="addNew_SingleField($index)">Single Line Text</button>
 <div id="drop"></div>

 <form ng-show="showName">
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Field Label(?)</label>
   <br/>
   <input ng-model="singleField.single">
  </div>
 </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code ?

Comment: @SambhavGore ok sure

Comment: @Mytri i have used global variable only.. ok i am updating my code

Comment: @VijjuSena see it is not a big issue if you post your code you'll get answers very quickly.

Comment: You have to update the model value or else play with the length of the `array`. Counter is not required..

Comment: @RayonDabre i updated my code.

Comment: @Mytri i updated my code

Comment: @SambhavGore i updated my code

Comment: @SambhavGore i updated my code

Comment: No..No...`ng-repeat` is the way to go...

Comment: @RayonDabre if i use ng-repeat .. when i reopen the saved form it has showing added values invisible, if i added field again.. it was adding multiple times, that is why i have used counter and appended values,, i have to add different type of fields in a single form..

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) in order to store the counter value in between sessions. Replace `var counter = 0;` with something like

```
var counter; 
if(localStorage['counter'] != undefined){
    counter = JSON.stringify(localStorage['counter']).value;
}
else{
    counter = 0;
}
```

Note that you should save your counter as a property of an object, like `localStorage['counter'] = {value: 5}` otherwise your index will be cast to a string.

This would work after opening / closing the page. If you were talking about maintaining the counter past the scope being destroyed (say on a page navigation), then you could use an [angular service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services), although using `localStorage` can also work in this case.

Comment: means have to replace ur code instead of using var counter = 0; right?

Comment: where to use **localStorage['counter'] = {value: }**

Comment: I tried with ur code,, i am not getting result this is my code [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/sutesolewu/edit?html,js,output) . can u pls adjust in this code ?

Comment: When you run `++counter` it isn't updating the localStorage value. You need to do `localStorage['counter'] = {value: 5}` after updating the value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save the counter value so that it continues from the last value on reload you could use a simple service to hold the value. If you want to persist this value in local storage or a cookie you could extend the function to that.

```
    angular.
    module('myServiceModule', []).     
    factory('counterService', [function() {
       var _counter = 0;

       function _get() {        
                return _counter;            
        }

       function _set(value) {
               _counter = value;
       }


        return {
            get: _get,
            set: _set
        }
     }]);
```

The main changes to your controller would be to get the counter starting value from the service. Then update the service with the changed counter value.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize', 'myServiceModule']);

app.controller('AddCtrl', function ($scope, $compile, counterService) {
$scope.singleFields = [];
    var counter = counterService.get(); //gets the current value from service
    for(var i =0; i < counter; i++){
      $scope.addNew_SingleField(i);
    }

    $scope.addNew_SingleField = function (index) {
        $scope.singleFields[counter] = {single: 'untitled'};
        var singlehtml = '<div ng-click="selectSingle(singleFields[\'' + counter + '\'])">\n\
<label>{{singleFields[' + counter + '].single}}</label>\n\
<input type="text"></div>';
        var single = $compile(singlehtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('drop')).append(single);
        ++counter;
        counterService.set(counter); //make sure to update the stored value
    };
    $scope.selectSingle = function (val) {
        $scope.singleField = val;
        $scope.showName = true;
    };
});
```

Comment: what is 'myServiceModule' in code,, is it app name or, service name ?

Comment: Thats just a new module name. You could copy the factory into an existing module you already have. Alternatively you could include this new module in your app. eg. var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myServiceModule']);

Comment: that means don't have to use var counter = 0; in my code? have to add just 'counter named factory' code of ur's??

Comment: i updated my answer, the main changes would be to read the initial value, then update the value when it changes. So that way its stored in case the controller is reloaded.

Comment: Hi tried ur code,,  but i am not getting proper result.. can u pls check this plunkr link [Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/2ou2xQWF1JsauRcBIlcO?p=preview) and adjust the code that is there any mystakes in my code..

Comment: As much as I understand your intentions, it appears to work? Can you better explain what you want it to do?

Comment: i want to add different fields to save in a form,, but when i opened and started adding fields into that form,, the counter is starting from '0'.. if the counter ended at '5'. it will start from 6 to so on .. but it was starting from '0'.. with that number it has already added in starting only.. that is my problem ..

Comment: Well if you are actually shutting your browser and re-opening it then angular will restart. So the service will start back at 0. If you want it to save in that case you need to put the value in Localstorage or a cookie and reload it.

If the counter is > 0 when the controller starts you need to recreate the form elements 

for(var i =0; i < counter; i++){
      addNew_SingleField(i);
    }

If you actually want to save the singleElements themselves then expand the counter service to store the items.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your code is really not correct. In Angular you don't really manipulate the DOM in the controller code. Your counter isn't needed really. Simply push onto your array with each click, then pass the reference to the element in your repeat statement.

In your template you could use an ng-repeat instruction:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<body ng-controller="AddCtrl">
    <button ng-click="addNew_SingleField()">Single Line Text</button>
    <div id="drop">
      <div ng-repeat="item in singleFields" ng-click="selectSingle(item)">
        <label>{{item.single}}</label>
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
</div>

    <form ng-show="showName">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Field Label(?)</label>
            <br/>
            <input ng-model="singleField.single">
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Then just simplify the add new function.

```
$scope.addNew_SingleField = function (index) {

        $scope.singleFields.push({single: 'untitled'}); 
    };
```

You array of single items should remain until you change state.

Comment: if i use ng-repeat, my further functionalities won't work properly